# UIScrollView zoomToRect scrolls the view when It should not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I made a simple test project to show the problem:
there is an imageview which is contained in scrollview 
view -> scrollview -> imageview

scrollview's content size is same as imageview size = (AllWidth, AllHeight).

The problem is that if scrollview is scaled EXACTLY to fit image by width (`scrollView.zoomScale = 320.0/AllWidth;`) then calling zoomToRect

```
[scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0.0,  0.0, AllWidth, AllHeight) animated: NO];
```

does scroll imageview to the bottom for some reason. But nothing is expected to happen with UI

if scrollview is NOT scaled EXACTLY to fit image by width (`scrollView.zoomScale = (320.0-1)/AllWidth;`), then calling zoomToRect does what is expected - image is scaled and not scrolled to the bottom.

i noticed that in 'buggy' case ContentOffset.y is changed, but i have no any idea why.

to reproduce the issue, start new project, in viewcontroller.h file add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`; viewcontroller.m is here: http://pastebin.com/bPUtuYn1 (in test project you will need double tap green image, then change "320.0-1" to "320.0" and try again)

Comment: Just a thought ... Make both AllWidth and AllHeight CGFloat rather than int, or cast everything to CGFloat, ie: scrollView.zoomScale = 320.0/ (CGFloat) AllWidth ; What happens?

Comment: same things happens. imageview moves down.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?